# Calling a static member function of a C++ STL container's value_type

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to get my head around why the following doesn't work. I have a std::vector and I want to call a static member function of it's contained value_type like so:

```
std::vector<Vector> v;
unsigned u = v.value_type::Dim();
```

where Vector is in fact a typedef for a templated type:

```
template <typename T, unsigned U> class SVector; 
typedef SVector<double, 2> Vector; //two-dimensional SVector containing doubles
```

and the static member function Dim() actually inlines the dimensionality U of the Vector.

Now the compiler returns an error message saying:

```
 error: ‘SVector<double, 2u>’ is not a base of 
 ‘std::vector<SVector<double, 2u>, std::allocator<SVector<double, 2u> > >
```

which puzzles me. I can replace the apparently offending line by

```
unsigned u = Vector::Dim();
```

and that works, but is obviously ugly as it hardcodes assumptions about the value_type of v... 
Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are accessing the value_type trough the variable instance and not the variable type.

**Method 1** - this works:

```
typedef std::vector<Vector> MyVector;
MyVector v;
unsigned u = MyVector::value_type::Dim();
```

**Method 2** - or this:

```
std::vector<Vector> v;
unsigned u = std::vector<Vector>::value_type::Dim();
```

If you typedef like on method 1 you do not hardcode assumptions on vector template parameter and you write clean code.

---

**Edit:** Expanded to explain the behavior for this issue as requested by question owner:

The scope resolution operator `::` has higher [precedence](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence) than any other C++ operator. This includes the Member access from an object `.` operator. Thus when you write something like:

```
unsigned u= v.value_type::Dim();
```

this resolves to the following C++ code:

```
unsigned u = v.SVector<double, 2>::Dim();
```

and ultimately what is resolved first is the `SVector<double, 2>::Dim()` part. This would force the vector instance declared trough variable `v` to have a templatized inner class named SVector. And because this does not happen this results in error:

```
error C2039: 'SVector<double,2>' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'
```

STL `vector` would have to be "expanded" for each usage of this pattern (accessing value_type trough variable instance and not variable type). This is not a good solution as it leads to lots of boilerplate and **unnecessary and unmaintainable code**. By following the above mentioned solutions you avoid all this and can easily do what you wanted.

Comment: Many thanks, that's great. I didn't know it was not allowed to access the value_type through the instance. Would you by any chance know why this is not allowed (what would go wrong if it was allowed)?

Comment: @yungchin check if the explanation that I just added is clear enough about this issue.

Comment: nothing would go wrong if it was allowed - since C++ is statically typed it already knows v is a std::vector<Vector>, but then again YOU already know what v is too, so it makes no difference really. I'm guessing the C++ designers wanted clear separation between static members and instance members.

Comment: @Greg and smink: awesome, thanks. It's completely clear to me now.